# Have 1/2 switched wall outlet. Adding ceiling fan using existing wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

EDIT: Success!  (1 down, 1 to go!)  Just need to tidy up the wiring and close up the junction box in the attic.  Total PITA but so worth it when the kid is super happy.  :)

[image: Success!]

Original Post:   Not 100% sure what I'm seeing here.  I have an existing single switch in a bedroom which operates a 1/2 outlet (1/2 hot all the time, other 1/2 to a floor lamp via the light switch).

I located the wiring in the attic (14/3) running almost directly over where I installed the mounting kit between the trusses - and would like to wire said ceiling fan using the existing switch and make the full outlet hot all the time.  Advise on how easiest to do this?  Thanks in advance! Long time lurker, 1st time question poster.

-John
:)

[image]
[image]

More pics added:

[image: new pic - wall switch 1]

[image: new pic - wall switch 2]

[image: new pic - outlet 1]

[image: new pic - outlet 2]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the boxes in question please?

Comment: Under "more pics added" there's 4 new ones. 1st 2 are wall switch, last 2 are the outlet.

Comment: Why are painters so lazy as to not put a piece of wide tape over boxes to protect the wiring when they're painting? Is it really _that_ hard? Sheesh!

Comment: @FreeMan - I have no idea!  Like seriously... "That wire is white, but it's actually black."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most direct way to do this would be to add 2 junction boxes in the attic.

the 14-3 from the switch to the outlet cut that with enough length to make it to the ceiling fan.

now you have a wire from the switch to the ceiling fan.

add a 14-2 from the ceiling fan to the rest of the 14-3 that goes to the outlet. add a junction box at that location. connect the red wire to the black ones. white to white. bare to bare.

in the ceiling fan connect the red to the ceiling fan and the black to the 14-2 black. connect all whites together

this way you won't have to cut sheetrock. and you won't have to rewire the devices.

the other way to do this is to fish a new wire from the switch to the ceiling fan recommend 14-3 so you can switch the fan separate from the light.

the only reason i don't recommend this is puling the switch box out of the wall and replacing it can be a pain. but ill walk you threw that if you want.

Comment: Thanks RadioSpace! That makes sense. Just trying to make it as easy as possible (so my teenager can stop whining that the new house doesn't have a fan in her room).

I'll give this a go and report back on progress.

Comment: Just want to say a big thanks for your instructions, @RadioSpace ! The worst part was slithering through the attic 6 or 7 times - where there's as little as 18" of space to work. I still need to tidy up everything but I have a function fan and light (and a happy kid!).   Thumbs up!

Comment: @JohnInAz no problem man. glad it worked out. hope it wasn't to hot.